# Xamarin Live Player - Deploy was cancelled

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-live-player

I have trying to debug my android app through Xamarin Live Player , it gets builds but give the error `Deploy was cancelled.`

Has anyone faced this and got this working .

Answer (score 1):

[Xamarin Live player Limitations](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/limitations/#Limitations)

- Some system classes cannot be overridden (for example, you cannot implement a subclass).
- Some platform features that require provisioning can't work in the Xamarin Live Player app (however it has been configured for common operations like camera access).
- Custom targets and build steps are ignored. For example, tools like Fody cannot be incorporated.

xamarin live player still not stable and there are issues that everyone complain. until it release high stable update best thing to deploy over usb connection

also see this  -

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/troubleshooting/

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussions/tagged/xamarin-live-player