# xamarin Live Player Lost connection

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-live-player

I am trying to connect to Xamarin Live player. My phone is samsung SM-J727V. My Visual studio version is Visual studio 2017 enterprise version is 15.6.4. Whenever I select the Pair Visual studio and scan the QR code from Visual studio screen. It establishes the connection and says connected to Visual studio and then after few minutes it says lost connection to visual studio.I tried pairing again and again and every time the connection is lost.

I looked through online articles, but could not find the solution. I do have some images in my Visual studio application. These images reside in Resources\draw able location I have latest Xamarin version and latest Visual studio enterprise edition. I am not sure what am I missing. I really want to use Live player because it will help me to see my changes instantaneously rather than waiting for the emulator to load.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any logs for your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xamarin live player still not stable and there are issues that everyone complain. until it release high stable update best thing to do is deploy over usb connection

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48743726/9326622

Comment: The link that you have provided above is not working

Comment: Same problem for me. Than, you are right its better USB connection.

Answer (score 1):

I had all kind of problems getting Xamarin Live Player to work. Finally I was able to have Visual Studio to connect to my mobile phone when starting/debugging the application. This is what I did:

- Download the Xamarin Live Player app from the App store and install in on on my mobile phone
- In Visual Studio, go to Tools > Xamarin Live Players > Manage Devices... and add my phone to Xamarin Live Players managed devices by scanning the QR code with the Xamarin Live Player app.

It did connect, but only for a few seconds.

- Start Developers Mode in Windows

In Windows 10: Start Settings app to access it. Go to Settings > Update & Security > For Developers and select “Developer mode”.

- Start Developers Mode on my mobile.

On my phone (Android 5.1.1): Go to Settings > Build Number and tab 7 times on it.

- Connect the phone with the PC using an USB cable

The Xamarin Live Player did not stayed connected. As soon as I started to debug the app, the Xamarin Live Player did connect and the app was visible on my phone.

Maybe it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by pressing following key combinations shift + Alt + F5 and its works